# How do i call different jquery javascript functions from one js file in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html file code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="carousel.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vertical_slider.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="glow-effect.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.4-packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="java_script.js"></script>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="carousel-wrapper">
                <img id="shadow" src="img/gui/carousel_shadow.png" />
                <div id="carousel">
                    <span id="pixar"><img src="img/large/pixar.jpg" /></span>
                    <span id="bugs"><img src="img/large/bugs.jpg" /></span>
                    <span id="cars"><img src="img/large/cars.jpg" /></span>
                    <span id="incred"><img src="img/large/incred.jpg" /></span>
                    <span id="monsters"><img src="img/large/monsters.jpg" /></span>
                    <span id="nemo"><img src="img/large/nemo.jpg" /></span>
                    <span id="radar"><img src="img/large/radar002665.png" /></span>
                    <span id="rat"><img src="img/large/rat.jpg" /></span>
                    <span id="toystory"><img src="img/large/toystory.jpg" /></span>
                    <span id="up"><img src="img/large/up.jpg" /></span>
                    <span id="walle"><img src="img/large/walle.jpg" /></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="thumbs-wrapper">
                <div id="thumbs">
                    <a href="#pixar" class="selected"><img src="img/small/pixar.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#bugs"><img src="img/small/bugs.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#cars"><img src="img/small/cars.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#incred"><img src="img/small/incred.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#monsters"><img src="img/small/monsters.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#nemo"><img src="img/small/nemo.jpg" /></a>
                            <a href="#radar"><img src="img/small/radar002665resized.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#rat"><img src="img/small/rat.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#toystory"><img src="img/small/toystory.jpg"  /></a>
                    <a href="#up"><img src="img/small/up.jpg" /></a>
                    <a href="#walle"><img src="img/small/walle.jpg" /></a>
                </div>
                <a id="prev" href="#"></a>
                <a id="next" href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slideshow">
            <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach4.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach5.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

On the bottom the class slideshow is another jquery.
The vertical_slider.

In the javascript file i called it java_script.js i did:

```
$(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    });

    $('#carousel').carouFredSel({
        responsive: true,
        circular: false,
        auto: false,
        items: {
            visible: 1,
            width: 200,
            height: '56%'
        },
        scroll: {
            fx: 'directscroll'
        }
    });

    $('#thumbs').carouFredSel({
        responsive: true,
        circular: false,
        infinite: false,
        auto: false,
        prev: '#prev',
        next: '#next',
        items: {
            visible: {
                min: 2,
                max: 6
            },
            width: 150,
            height: '66%'
        }
    });

    $('#thumbs a').click(function() {
        $('#carousel').trigger('slideTo', '#' + this.href.split('#').pop() );
        $('#thumbs a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Where this part:

```
$('.slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
});
```

Is for the slideshow and the rest is for the second jquery the carousel.
And now both jquery not working. On the slideshow in the javascript file i'm getting error when doing inspect element:  Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on line nubmer 3

Line 3 in the javascript file is:

```
$('.slideshow').cycle({
```

If i put the slideshow javascript code in the html file inside script tags it will work but i want it to be with the other javascript codes in the java_script.js file.

Comment: Did you also load the cycle plugin..?

Comment: you would have included `java_script.js` before `jQuery` or `Cycle` plugin.

Comment: Try to create two different functions in the same .js file. Or just erase the $(function() { } at the beginning.

Comment: Cerlin Boss and Spokey was right. I forgot to include the Cucle plugin now it's working. Thank you everyone.